# Databricks- Can we variablize the mount_point name during creation by passing the value from SQL lookup table

Tags: python, sql, databricks, azure-data-factory, azure-databricks

Thanks  in Advance this site is of greathelp!!!!

Question:

Can we get variabliize the mount_point name and the filename while creating the data frame.

Mount name: select company from comaytable(pass the comapy name as mountpoint variable)

source = "wasbs://uidbddnnps@dmoddddssa.blob.core.windows.net",
mount_point = "/mnt/"**VARIABLIZENAME**",
extra_configs = {"fs.azure.sas.uiasasps.dmodssdsdgarea.blob.core.windows.net":dbutils.secrets.get(scope = "AIdsT", key = "keydmodslaarea")})
print("=> Succeeded")

File Name Variablzie:

df = spark.read.format("csv").option("sep", ",").options(header= "true", inferschema='true').option('escape','"').load("/mnt/AT/VARIABLIZE.csv")

Can we pass this values from datafactory also i can make use of it if necessary

Comment: If the answer is helpful for you, you can accept it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.). This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You may checkout the steps mentioned below:

**Step1:** Declaring the variables:

```
mountname = 'test'
csvname = 'original.csv'
path = "dbfs:/mnt/{0}/{1}".format(mountname,csvname)
```

**Step2:** Mounting the storage account

```
dbutils.fs.mount(
  source = "wasbs://test@chepra.blob.core.windows.net/",
  mount_point = "/mnt/{0}".format(mountname),
  extra_configs = {"fs.azure.sas.test.chepra.blob.core.windows.net":"gv7nXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXlOiA=="})
print("=> Succeeded")
```

**Step3:** Creating the Spark Dataframe

```
df = spark.read.format("csv").option("sep", ",").options(header= "true", inferschema='true').option('escape','"').load("{0}".format(path))
```

[image]

Comment: thnks a lot , just wanted to know if we could get the data what u have assiged in step1 from SQL query and then use this values further

Comment: @malcolmrichard To get variable from SQL query you may checkout the solution provide by Himanshu.

Comment: You can accept it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.). This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Just to understand you have a ADF where you are calling a lookup ( running a SQL query ) and the intent is that you want to pass the value from the Lookup to a notebook .

If thats the case we can achieve this by implementing a Lookup acitivity and  a foreach ( to loop in the all the records . Inside the foreach please use a Notebook activity , point this to the notebook which you want to run and pass value of the company ( something as @item() etc ) https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-lookup-activity .

On the notebook  you can use the widget and get the value as incoming parameter .

CompanyName = dbutils.widgets.get("CompanyName")

Please let me know if you have any questions .